# How do i change the back testing range in pinescript version 5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

the back testing range is not changeable and has a mind of its own, it was going for 10 days, 31/7 until 10/8 then it reset to 3 days ago but i want it longer and i dont know how to change it

I try to change the back testing range in the properties section but its unchangeable so i google it and find a code for it so i add a few lines of code that adds a calendar i can pick dates on in the input menu this also changes nothing and the backtesting range remains the same, is the problem that my account is not premium that i cant customize the date?